# How to properly check for updates in a CDN?

Tags: java, cdn

I have a CDN, which stores avatars, one can get access to an avatar by hashing user's id and using it as a file name. I only get an avatar for a user and store it locally. But if a user decides to update his/her avatar, user does it through a different service. Once user updates his avatar, filename in the CDN does not change, but the file itself changes. So, the question is: how, from backend perspective, should I check for updates in CDN in order to always store the most recent avatar locally?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in this field is to make resources idempotent (ie. the content associated to a name cannot change, each content gets a unique name).

So if the user changes his avatar, you are actually creating a new resource with a new name.
You save the name as an attribute of the user profile and forget about the old one.
When you want to display his avatar you look up for the name of the resource.
The CDN caches this new content.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over CDN and its naming policies and since upon changing the avatar user's id stays the same, the name does not change and there is no way for me to affect it.

Comment: I'm suggesting to replace the part "hashing user's id and using it as a file name". This part has nothing to do with the CDN. Do you control the way you retrieve the file name associated with a user id?

Comment: I do not retrieve it in any way, I can only get user's id and then hash it to get the filename.